# Jquery Array To Table "TD"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array (created dynamically) that would look like [one,two,three,four,five,six]

I have a table (created dynamically) with the same number of rows as items in the array

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><td>
     <td>content</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><td>
     <td>content</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><td>
     <td>content</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><td>
     <td>content</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><td>
     <td>content</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><td>
     <td>content</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

My goal, is to  place the array item in the  td:first-of-type in the row with the corresponding index() value as array position.

I generally dont ask question this early on, but I'm clueless on how to go about doing this. This one is a little over my head?

Comment: Loop over the array and edit the corresponding `<td>`.  Something like `$('tr').eq(index).find('td:first').text()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`each` gives everything to you almost out-of-the-box:

```
$("tr").each(function(index, elem){
    $(this).find("td").first().text(yourArray[index]);
})
```

Comment: Ok, so here is the next bit im stuck on, I actually have multiple tables that are identicle to this (Structurly), this solutions stops after the first table, why would that be?

Comment: @Mark, might be related to the way you are selecting the `tr`s

Answer (score 2):

Ok, maybe loop through them like this:

```
$("table tr").each(function(index) {
      $(this).children("td").first().html(myArray[index]);
});
```

Comment: I'm sure that `"table > tr"` won't select any `tr` element as browser wraps the `tr`s with `tbody` element.

Comment: ah, good point. I'll just upvote Andrei in addition to correcting.

Comment: Well that doesn't mean that your answer is wrong, the logic was correct so +1.

Comment: Ok, so here is the next bit im stuck on, I actually have multiple tables that are identicle to this (Structurly), this solutions stops after the first table, why would that be?

Comment: are you trying to loop through all the tables or just a specific one? You might give your tables ids or classes to distinguish between them. Then you can just replace `$(table tr)` with `$(table#myId tr)` or `$("table.myClass tr")`